# Angular 10: Access NgControl in an Angular Material custom form field control

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to access NgControl within a custom [Angular Material Form Field Control](https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control):

```
constructor(
    @Self() @Optional() public ngControl: NgControl,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private fm: FocusMonitor,
    private elRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
  ) {
    this.createForm();

    console.log('<< ', this.ngControl);
    if (this.ngControl != null) {
      this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }

    fm.monitor(elRef.nativeElement, true).subscribe(origin => {
      this.focused = !!origin;
      this.stateChanges.next();
    });
  }
```

But when I do this the interface where I use the component is blank, no errors!
When I remove the NgControl from the constructor the view is rendered.

Is that the way to inject NgControl?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Injecting ngControl directly in constructor causes cyclic dependency.
Can be avoided by doing this:

```
constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
    ...
  ) {
    ...
  }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ngControl = this.injector.get(NgControl);
  }
```